# Pandas pop last row

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to get and remove last row like `pop` method of python native list?

I know I can do like below. I just want to make it one line.

```
df.ix[df.index[-1]]
df = df[:-1]
```

Comment: One liner: `last_row, df = df.iloc[-1], df.iloc[:-1]`

Answer (score 10):

Suppose sample dataframe:

```
In[51]:df
Out[51]: 
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8
```

you can do using [df.drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
In[52]:df,last_row=df.drop(df.tail(1).index),df.tail(1)

In[53]:df
Out[53]: 
   0  1
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7

In[54]:last_row
Out[54]: 
   a  b
3  4  8
```

or using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) as `np`:

```
df,last_row=pd.Dataframe(np.delete(df.values,(-1),axis=0)),df.tail(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I tested two ways to do this: **df = df[: -1]** and **df = df.drop(df.index[-1])**. The first one is much more efficient

Here is the test with 3000 rows.

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
while df.shape[0] > 1:
    df = df.drop(df.index[-1])
print(datetime.now() - start)
```

result: 0:00:01.558176

and,
df = df.drop(df.index[-1])

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
while prices.shape[0] > 1:
    prices = prices[: -1]
print(datetime.now() - start)
```

result: 0:00:00.337987