# How to pop rows from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I found the documentation for [`pandas.DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), but after trying it and examining the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/core/generic.py#L521-L532), it does not seem to do what I want.

If I make a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,6))
# Make a few areas have NaN values
df.iloc[1:3,1] = np.nan
df.iloc[5,3] = np.nan
df.iloc[7:9,5] = np.nan


>>> df
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  0.772762 -0.442657  1.245988  1.102018 -0.740836  1.685598
1 -0.387922       NaN -1.215723 -0.106875  0.499110  0.338759
2  0.567631       NaN -0.353032 -0.099011 -0.698925 -1.348966
3  1.320849  1.084405 -1.296177  0.681111 -1.941855 -0.950346
4 -0.026818 -1.933629 -0.693964  1.116673  0.392217  1.280808
5 -1.249192 -0.035932 -1.330916       NaN -0.135720 -0.506016
6  0.406344  1.416579  0.122019  0.648851 -0.305359 -1.253580
7 -0.092440 -0.243593  0.468463 -1.689485  0.667804       NaN
8 -0.110819 -0.627777 -0.302116  0.630068  2.567923       NaN
9  1.884069 -0.393420 -0.950275  0.151182 -1.122764  0.502117
```

If I want to remove selected rows and assign them to a separate object in one step, I would want a `pop` behavior, like this:

```
# rows in column 5 which have NaN values
>>> df[df[5].isnull()].index
Int64Index([7, 8], dtype='int64')

# remove them from the dataframe, assign them to a separate object
>>> nan_rows = df.pop(df[df[5].isnull()].index)
```

However, this does not appear to be supported. Instead, it seems like I am forced to do this in two separate steps, which seems a bit inelegant.

```
# get the NaN rows
>>> nan_rows = df[df[5].isnull()]

>>> nan_rows
          0         1         2         3         4   5
7 -0.092440 -0.243593  0.468463 -1.689485  0.667804 NaN
8 -0.110819 -0.627777 -0.302116  0.630068  2.567923 NaN

# remove from orignal df
>>> df = df.drop(nan_rows.index)

>>> df
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  0.772762 -0.442657  1.245988  1.102018 -0.740836  1.685598
1 -0.387922       NaN -1.215723 -0.106875  0.499110  0.338759
2  0.567631       NaN -0.353032 -0.099011 -0.698925 -1.348966
3  1.320849  1.084405 -1.296177  0.681111 -1.941855 -0.950346
4 -0.026818 -1.933629 -0.693964  1.116673  0.392217  1.280808
5 -1.249192 -0.035932 -1.330916       NaN -0.135720 -0.506016
6  0.406344  1.416579  0.122019  0.648851 -0.305359 -1.253580
9  1.884069 -0.393420 -0.950275  0.151182 -1.122764  0.502117
```

Is there a one-step method built-in? Or is this the way you're 'supposed' to do it?

Comment: This question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263411/pandas-pop-last-row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas pop last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263411/pandas-pop-last-row)

Answer (score 4):

Since you can pop columns, you can take transpose of the dataframe and pop its columns, ie. the rows of the original df like this. Here is the original df.

```
    import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(3, 3)), columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

print(df)
   a  b  c
0  4  9  4
1  5  5  8
2  5  7  4
```

Then you take transpose of it and pop column 0 which is the row 0 of the original df.

```
df_t = df.T
popped_row = df_t.pop(0)
```

Now you have the popped row

```
print(popped_row)
a    4
b    9
c    4
Name: 0, dtype: int32
```

And then you have the original dataframe without the first row.

```
df = df_t.T

print(df)
   a  b  c
1  5  5  8
2  5  7  4
```

Comment: but how is this approach any better than the approach OP has? It has more lines of code, is less efficient, and is harder to read

Comment: I think this is a question of a taste. The original post was after a solution that works like pop method - and I provided such a solution. It is up to you to decide which you like more. Actually both solutions can be expressed on two lines, if that is what you want. I think often it is better not to minimise lines of code

Answer (score 2):

pop source code:

> ```
>     def pop(self, item):
>         """
>         Return item and drop from frame. Raise KeyError if not found.
>         """
>         result = self[item]
>         del self[item]
>         try:
>             result._reset_cacher()
>         except AttributeError:
>             pass
>
>         return result
> File:      c:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
> ```

`del` definitely won't work if `item` is not a simple column name. Pass a simple column name, or do it in two steps.

Comment: yes that is what I meant by what I posted in the OP. `pop` only works on columns here, not rows.

Comment: So what do you expect? It s SO not GH :-)

Comment: not sure what GH is. It seemed like there would be a one-step method for this which I hadn't found yet.

Comment: GitHub : you re searching for a feature that is not implemented in pop.

Comment: yes I am searching for other/better implementations of the feature I described